# Not able to create a directory using sudo -u username mkdir /var/log/test

Tags: linux, shell, centos, sudo, sudoers

I am unable to create a directory using `sudo` priveleges from root user and If I login to user , I can create an directory under /root using `sudo`. Also I have added to allow all commands in `/etc/sudoers` file and the details are below:

```
[root@linux home]# cat /etc/sudoers | grep  tes
test  ALL= NOPASSWD: ALL
```

## **Error**

> [root@linux home]# sudo -u test mkdir /var/log/test3
>
> mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/var/log/test3’: Permission denied

Any Ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I am able to create the directory If login as user using sudo.  Please let me know the sufficient permission for user to create directory using commads ( sudo -u username mkdir /var/log/test)

Answer (score 1):

By running 'sudo -u test', you're giving yourself lower privileges than the roor user because you're running the command as the user 'test', not 'root'. From the root user, you can just run:

`mkdir /var/log/test3`

Read `man sudo` for more info.

Or:

Run `visudo` and uncomment the wheel group, then add the user test to the wheel group.

If you don't mind me asking, why do you need to create a directory as a certain user from the root user? Especially since the directory you're making will not be user specific?

Also, in the sudoers file , you should what added `test ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`, not `test ALL= NOPASSWD: ALL`

Comment: I have an binary file which creates multiple directory and files which under /root. While executing the binary file  , folders are not creating due to permission issue but binary file is running with user ownership.Any ideas ?

Comment: I can't comment on any post on my own, so I've been updating my original post. But that sounds like an ownership issue, not a

Comment: But that sounds like an ownership issue, not a system privilege escalation issue. Give this a look: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php?title=File_permissions_and_attributes&redirect=no#Changing_ownership

Comment: Sorry, the whole page, not just that section.